# set the object name to the value of a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i name the object with the value of url?

```
let url = 'https://example.com/'
const obj = new constr(img) //i want to name this object (obj) with the ulr's string

class constr(img){
    this.img = img;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "name this object"?

Comment: @Quentin i want to create an object named as example.com

Comment: What do you mean by "name"? Objects don't generally have names (functions are the main exception) so its really unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to create an object like that 
https://example.com/{
prop1:'....'
}

Comment: I want to store some objects in a json file can they have the same name?

Comment: Objects in JSON have nothing to do with what you've asked in this question (and also don't have names as a feature).

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by "an object like example.com{ prop1:'....' }". If you console.log an object that is an instance of a class then **some** debuggers will display the class name as a prefix to the object data. Is that what you mean?  If so, you should stop as it would require some horribly hacking to create dynamic function constructors to make that happen.

Comment: Probably you're trying to create an example of what you want to achieve to make it more clear, but I'm not sure that it will work that way. Do you have a specific need or issue and you ended up with this "name the object with a value" solution? It could help knowing that first issue, maybe it can be solved in a different (or more clear) way.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand correctly, this should work

```
let obj = {
  url: 'https://example.com/'
};
```

Or a shorthand, because you've the variable `url` defined,

```
let obj = {
      url
};
```